# Unable to delete a record from one of the tabs on sstab

Tags: vb6

I have developed a form in vb6.0 and have put sstab. Now I am struck while deleting a single record from one of the tabs. The below code is my attempt to delete all the records present on the tab in one go!!

```
Private Sub CmdDelete_Click()
 On Error GoTo ErrTrap 
Dim QRY As String 
' If bolNewRec Then Exit Sub 
If MsgBox("Are you sure to delete the current employee details?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub 
QRY = "Delete from ac_branch_employees where gl_code = '" & GLCode & "' and sl_code = '" & SLCode & "'" 
ConnHalo.Execute QRY 
rsBranchEmp.Requery 
Screen.MousePointer = ccDefault

cmdNew_Click

Exit Sub
ErrTrap: ErrorHandle End Sub
```

visual-basic-6

Comment: check the error, if any, after Execute.

Answer (score 0):

You should really give more information as to what your problem is, but I will take a guess in saying that you are expecting this line:

```
rsBranchEmp.Requery
```

To redisplay your data, which it won't do alone (it only fetches an updated recordset from the previous query). You will have to repopulate whichever control you are using to display the data with the updated recordset.